# Counting Characteristic Polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, polynomials

> ***Question:*** Let  $M_n$ be the set of all square $n \times n$ $(0,1)$-matrices. I write $$\mathbf{char}(M_n)=\{\chi(X)\text{ }|\text{ }\chi(X)\text{ is the characteristic polynomial for some matrix in } M_n. \}$$ How do I compute  the order of $\mathbf{char}(M_n)$ ?

For example:  $M_2$ has [$16$ distinct](https://oeis.org/A002416) matrices with $6$ distinct characteristic polynomials:
$$\mathbf{char}(M_2)=\{X^2,X^2-X,X^2-2X+1,X^2-X-1,X^2-2X,X^2-1\}$$

I know that [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) matrices have the same characteristic polynomial but the converse is false. I am not certain the question is equivalent to counting similar matrices ?

Comment: Is the $n$ in $M_n$ meant to be the same as the $n$ in $q = p^n$? Along similar lines, it's not clear what field you are working over in your example: $|M_2| = 16$ would imply you're working over $\Bbb F_2$ but your list of characteristic polynomials includes $X^2 - 2X$ which equals $X^2$ in a field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: I will edit and correct the question.

Comment: This is [OEISA272661](http://oeis.org/A272661).  No formula is given.

Comment: The [slides](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stevenethornton.github/BHIME+Slides.pdf) linked to in the OEIS entry seem helpful also (with some nice visuals.)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, I had misunderstood the question

For any monic polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ over a field $K$, one can construct its [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) which is an $n \times n$ matrix over $K$ with characteristic polynomial $p$. Therefore counting the number of possible characteristic polynomials of $n \times n$ matrices over $K$ is the same as counting the number of possible monic polynomials of degree $n$ over $K$, i.e. $|K|^n$.

Comment: Hmm so then my example is wrong ? We should only have $4$ distinct characteristic polynomials ? Also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2176849/a-method-to-count-the-number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-of-degree-2-or-3-o)

Comment: The OP not considering matrices over a finite field.  He's considering matrices (over the rationals, say) that happen to have only 0's and 1's.

Comment: Yes @JairTaylor

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you @JairTaylor

Comment: @JairTaylor can you answerize your comment so I can throw you some points. And it appears the formula $\mathbf{char}(M_n)$ is not know.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez It doesn't really seem like an answer to me - I'm interested if anyone else has anything to say here.  But thanks :)